# How do you turn an HTML unordered list into jQuery autocomplete?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, autocomplete

I have a long, unordered list on a page. It looks something like this

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="http://www.google.com">
      Google
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="http://www.yahoo.com">
      Yahoo
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Instead of displaying a list of links, I'd rather display it as a jQuery autocomplete where typing "Ya" will display the word "Yahoo" and when clicked (or after pressing "Enter") will take you to its href.

Is there any way I can get the contents of this dynamically changing list and display it instead as an autocomplete?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are using [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/),

**Step 1** - Add an text input for your autocomplete:

```
<input type="text" id="search" />
```

**Step 2** - Convert your DOM to a list of links:

```
var items = [];

$('ul li a').each(function () {
    items.push({ 
        value: $(this).attr('href'),
        label: $(this).text()
    });
});

$('ul').remove();
```

**Step 3** - Turn on the autocomplete:

```
$("#search").autocomplete({
    source: items,
    select: function (event, ui) { 
        window.location.href = ui.item.value;
    }
});
```

Comment: I can't get it to work. I added the code to a JSFiddle [here] (http://jsfiddle.net/3L83d/)

Comment: yes yes yes!!!!!!! I have been trying to figure this out for the past few days. You're a lifesaver, Alon.

Comment: @AlonGubkin - This is almost what I am looking for as well but I'd like to take it a step further.  If I have an unordered list on a page, do you know how I can allow someone to type on the list and it will jump to an item in the list that matches?  Similar to how you can type in a dropdown to get down to items lower in the list...but instead of a dropdown, it's a UL.  Any ideas would be appreciated.